# Tensorflow.js prediction seems to have an upper limit of 1?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I was playing around with some tensorflow code I got from a youtube tutorial that predicts data of flowers. Here is the script (the training data is assigned to variable "iris" and the testing data is assigned to variable "irisTesting":

```
const trainingData = tf.tensor2d(iris.map(item => [
    item.sepal_length, item.petal_length, item.petal_width,
]));
const outputData = tf.tensor2d(iris.map(item => [
    item.species === "setosa" ? 1 : 0,
    item.species === "virginica" ? 1 : 0,
    item.species === "versicolor" ? 1 : 0,
    item.sepal_width
]));
const testingData = tf.tensor2d(irisTesting.map(item => [
    item.sepal_length, item.petal_length, item.petal_width
]));

const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [3],
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 5,
}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [5],
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 4,
}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 4,
}));
model.compile({
    loss: "meanSquaredError",
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(.06),
});
const startTime = Date.now();
model.fit(trainingData, outputData, {epochs: 100})
    .then((history) => {
         //console.log(history);
        console.log("Done training in " + (Date.now()-startTime) / 1000 + " seconds.");
        model.predict(testingData).print();
    });
```

When the console prints the predicted `sepal_width`, it seems to have an upper limit of 1. The training data has `sepal_width` values of well over 1, but here is the data that is logged:

```
Tensor
    [[0.9561102, 0.0028415, 0.0708825, 0.9997129],
     [0.0081552, 0.9410981, 0.0867947, 0.999761 ],
     [0.0346453, 0.1170913, 0.8383155, 0.9999373]]
```

The last (fourth) column would be the predicted `sepal_width` value. The predicted values should be larger than 1 however it seems that something is preventing it from being larger than 1.

This is the original code:
https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/a96d80a29538c7625652493c2407b6be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a sigmoid activation function in the final layer to predict the `sepal_width`. Sigmoid is continuous function bounded between 0 and 1. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) for a more thorough explanation.

You should try to use a different activation function if you want to predict the `sepal_width`. For a list of available activation functions you can check [Tensorflow's API page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Activation_Functions) (this is for the Python version, but the it should be similar for the JavaScript version). You can try `'softplus'`, `'relu'` or even `'linear'`, but I cannot say if any of these are suitable for your application. Try and experiment to see which is best.

Answer (score 1):

The activation function of your last layer is `sigmoid`.

The Sigmoid function looks like this:
[image: Sigmoid]

[source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Sigmoid-function-2.svg)

And as you can see it is restricted in the range of 0 to 1. So if you want other output values you need to adjust your last activation function accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The original code from [here](https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/a96d80a29538c7625652493c2407b6be) addresses a classification problem. It is not meaningful to add `item.sepal_width` in your `outputData` because it is not another class.